# how can I monitor SignalR host for deadlock or long running thread?

Tags: signalr

For a testing example, I have a hub public method, which has a long running loop.

```
public class testhub : Hub
{
  public void looptest()
  {
    while(true){ <do something>  }
  }

  public void chatmsg()
  {......}
}
```

client A connect hub and call it --> testhub.server.looptest
client B connect hub and call it --> testhub.server.looptest

As a server administrator , How can I monitor all the threads in the host hub, and kill any one I want, without shutting down the whole IIS or self-host hub?
for example, let's say i build a UI like this:

task         running time         action
----------   ------------         ------
looptest     5h33min              (button kill)
looptest     0h12min              (button kill)
chatmsg      1sec                 (button kill)

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly build in some metrics reporting using a custom [`IHubPipelineModule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubs.ihubpipelinemodule.aspx) that tracks active hub method executions so that you have the visibility you're looking for, but as far as "killing" anything there's no support for that. That would mean you would be wanting to kill a thread which has indeterminable side effects in any running program (.NET or otherwise) and you could never be sure that you haven't left the program in a bad overall state.

One thing you could probably do if you really needed this and wanted to go down a road of highly customizing the SignalR framework by is inject a custom hub method invocation implementation that maybe understands how to pass a [`CancellationToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx) parameter into method signatures that support it so that those methods could adhere to logical cancellation requests, but even that would be opt-in which means that the implementation would actually have to include a call to [`ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested.aspx) (or graceful check of [`IsCancellationRequested`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.iscancellationrequested.aspx)) somewhere within its looping logic.